# What card game are they playing in S02E12?

Tags: hibike-euphonium

In the twelfth episode of the second season of Hibike Euphonium, some of the main characters are playing a card game before going to bed.

Apparently it has to do something with reaching classes, because Kumiko mentions not even getting out of middle class after Midori announced that "Revolution's over".

[image: Revolutions over screenshot] 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This game is called **Capitalism** and each player is assigned a social class ranging from president to 'scum'.

It's also sometimes called **[President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_(card_game))** which is a westernized verison of the japanese game "[daifugō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daifug%C5%8D)" (perhaps that is the actual game, but localized) where it ranges from the daifugō (Grand millionaire) to the Daihinmin (Extreme Needy).

There is a variant which allows "revolutions"

> If a player leads out with four of a kind, the hierarchy of all the cards will be reversed.
>
> For example, if 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A,2 is the typical order of power (from left to right), after four of a kind is played it would be the reverse of that: 2,A,K,Q,J,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3.
>
> If another four of a kind is played, the order would switch back. Revolutions are typically utilized in the game to create better balance and avoid having the same player remain in first position indefinitely.

The object of the game of course is to be the highest ranking person :)

Comment: Ah, so it's similar to the game called asshole and is also referred to in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/what-is-the-card-game-the-characters-play)

Comment: @looper yep! looks like it